# Reporting services - custom library is not working after installing report on production Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I created a report which uses custom library created by me. I've copied these libraries to the following folders:

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting
>   Services\ReportServer\bin\
>
> c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>   8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\

Everything works fine when I run the report using on development environment using Visual Studio. When I install it on Production Server (where these dlls were also copied) the following error is returned:

> Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: The type initializer for 'MyParserForReportingServices.MyParser' threw an exception. (rsErrorLoadingExprHostAssembly) 
>   Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and copied the DLL to the ReportServer folder and worked!!

Weird because in the doc. the ReportManager is mentioned but ReportServer not.

Thanks Masoud!

Answer (score 3):

add your dll to this folder too

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting
>   Services\ReportManager\Bin